# is not defined at onload

Tags: javascript, symfony

I know this is an issue who comes again and again, but I can't find any clear solution.

I had a static html/js which were working fine (because it was only html and js, the scripts had the time to load and stuff like body onload were working).

But now I try to export this same page under a Symfony application

So as, in my twig I have this

```
<head>
    {% block stylesheets %}
        <link href="{{ asset('build/synopsis.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    {% endblock %}
    {% block scripts %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('build/synopsis.js') }}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
</head>

<body onload="drawStars()">
```

But now obviously, the drawStars function isn't loaded fast enough to make it work (or I think this is what happen).

And i'm getting

> Uncaught ReferenceError: drawStars is not defined
>       at onload

I'm looking for a way to prevent my all body to be generated before the script isn't fully loaded.

PS: I know it's bad to load script in header because slowing things, but there are some specific case when you want your script to be first fully loaded. Already tried to look with `async` or `defer` but without success.
Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Here is my synopsis.js file

```
require('../css/synopsis.css');

// Sets the number of stars we wish to display
const numStars = 100;

function drawStars() {
  // For every star we want to display
for (let i = 0; i < numStars; i++) {
  let star = document.createElement("div");  
  star.className = "star";
  var xy = getRandomPosition();
  star.style.top = xy[0] + 'px';
  star.style.left = xy[1] + 'px';
  document.body.append(star);
}
}


// Gets random x, y values based on the size of the container
function getRandomPosition() {  
  var y = window.innerWidth;
  var x = window.innerHeight;
  var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random()*x);
  var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random()*y);
  return [randomX,randomY];
}

 var audio=document.createElement('audio');
 var play=true;


function turn(){
  if(play){
      document.getElementsByClassName('soundOn')[0].innerHTML = "Musique Off";
      document.getElementsByClassName('soundOn')[0].style.backgroundColor="red";
      audio.src="musique/opening.mp3";
      audio.play();
    }else{
      document.getElementsByClassName('soundOn')[0].innerHTML = "Musique On";
      document.getElementsByClassName('soundOn')[0].style.backgroundColor="#4CAF50";
      audio.pause();
    }
    play = !play;

}
```

Comment: If `drawStars()` were a function defined globally inside that "synopsis.js" file your code would work. You didn't post that file however so it's going to be hard for anybody to spot the problem.

Comment: What about `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", drawStars);` at the very end of your page ?

Comment: @Pointy I've added the file content

Comment: Are you seeing any other errors?

Comment: Yes, when I try to click on one of my button with an on click element for the turn function...but basiclly it's the same error.

Comment: @Cid sadly, not working neither

Answer (score 0):

wait for the script to load than the body

```
<head>
    {% block stylesheets %}
        <link href="{{ asset('build/synopsis.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    {% endblock %}
    {% block scripts %}
        <script type="text/javascript" onload="drawStars()" src="{{ asset('build/synopsis.js') }}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>
```

But more logically, if you have to run a function from inside a js function after it loads, why not just write `drawStars()` on the last line of the file and it gets executed automatically once loaded?!

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean. If I want to use the script in many files/apges i'm not going to write it again in each page ? May be i'm just missing something

Comment: nope, I meant, if `drawStars()` is a function inside `synopsis.js` and if you want it to run after `synopsis.js` has loaded. Adding it to last line of `synopsis.js` would make sure that `drawStars()` is called in all the pages that include it in script

Comment: but again, if you dont want it to execute everytime on load, you can do the above approach in the question and call it `onload` of the script

Comment: I tried both of your solution, doing `yarn encore dev` and `php bin/console cache:clear` each time to get the good files and no cache issue. Still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution, I really really hope this will help people in the future...because the documentation about it is quite hard to find and I think not clear.

Eventually, I manage to handle what I need by doing 2 things

First one, as suspected by @Pointy, the function called needs to be defined as global

```
Window.prototype.drawStars = function () { ... }
```

But this alone is not enough, and this is where it's tricky because the documentation of webpack encore doesn't seems to be very clear about this.

But, we can't use this to link assets

But instead

```
{% block stylesheets %}{{ encore_entry_link_tags('synopsis') }}{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}{{ encore_entry_script_tags('synopsis') }}{% endblock %}
```

And of course, in the example of webpack encore they use this function, but it's never exaplained why we need to use this instead of the usual asset function.

So...I can't tell why this is working, may be it's just a workaround and not an actual solution, but it works as expected now.